# How to get a reference to the string value of google api key stored in google_maps_api.xml file?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created a map activity in android. I have set up the google api key in **google_maps_api.xml** file.

I want to use location api in some other class and I require to have a string reference to the api key as I don't want to redefine the key.

**I.e, I want to store api key in some String variable and use accordingly.**

I have tried `getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key)` But it says

> can't resolve method getResources

This also doesn't work

```
private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = getActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
```

Comment: `can't resolve method getResources` means that the class that you are trying to call this method from does not have this method

Comment: Try to write getActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key).

Comment: Please help me store api key in a string variable but I don't want to use raw api key rather I would like to fetch the api key string from xml file

Comment: @Ankita doesn't work

Comment: Show your code then.

Comment: @Ankita I have added the line of code in question.

Comment: @MONUKUMAR is it your *Fragment* or *Activity* ?

Comment: It is a custom class not an activity or fragment

Comment: @MONUKUMAR Then post code of that custom class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all define *GOOGLE_API_KEY* Globally inside *Activity* or *Fragment*. As below.

```
public static String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "";
```

If it is *Activity* then inside *onCreate* use below code.

```
GOOGLE_API_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
```

If it is *Fragment* then inside *onCreateView* use below code.

```
GOOGLE_API_KEY = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
```

Hope it will give you the way to go ahead.

Comment: Your method worked. Thanks! I suggested an edit, have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

If it's Activity:

```
   getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
```

If it's Fragment:

```
   getActivity().getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
```

if it's class:

**create contractor for your class:**

```
public static Context context;

    public  Yourclassname(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
 String GOOGLE_API_KEY = context.getString(R.string.appbar_scrolling_view_behavior);
```

And Pass your context inside your **activity**

```
Oncreate(){
         Yourjavaclassname  obj =  new Yourjavaclassname(this);
 }
```

Comment: doesn't work! i already tried this.  It says can't resolve method getString(int).I think It expects string as argument.

Comment: @MONUKUMAR You are using fragment or Activity

Comment: It is a Custom Class not an activity.

Comment: @MONUKUMAR Try this let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a constructor in your class:-

```
Context mContext;
 public ClassName(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }
```

Inside Class write

```
mContext.getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
```

And initialize this construtor in your activity and pass the reference like:-

```
ClassName name= new ClassName(this);
```